# quotes matching in os.system()

Tags: python, unix, quotes

```
os.system('''awk \'$1 == "RULE" && $8 !=0{print $2, $8}\' "{}/ABC*XYZ*" | sort -u >>error_file'''.format(path))
```

On executing this command using terminal the command works fine but using os.system() this is printing the error

```
KeyError: 'print $2, $8'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should understand what does `format` do. Two example:

```
'a{}c'.format('b')
>>> abc
'a{b}c'format(b='b')
>>> abc
```

If there is a empty bracket pair, format will pass params one by one. Other wise format will pass params by name.

Now you want to use format to fill a command, but in fact your command has two bracket paris, so it will try to fill all of them --- explicit, it will failed.

You should write '{{print $2, $8}}' if you just want to use a bracket text instead of fill something else. So your code should be:

```
os.system('''awk \'$1 == "RULE" && $8 !=0{{print $2, $8}}\' "{}/ABCXYZ" | sort -u >>error_file'''.format(path))
```

I don't know more about `awk`, so I'm not sure it can be work as what you want, but at least I'm pretty sure you don't need reverse slash here. It equals to

```
os.system('''awk '$1 == "RULE" && $8 !=0{{print $2, $8}}' "{}/ABCXYZ" | sort -u >>error_file'''.format(path))
```

And, an interesting point, I think you don't need, but just show here:

```
os.system('''awk '$1 == "RULE" && $8 !=0{print $2, $8}' "{}/ABCXYZ" | sort -u >>error_file'''.format(path, **{'print $2, $8': '{print $2, $8}'}))
```

Though you can't use `print $2, $8` as a param name, but in fact you can pass it as a dict key:)

Comment: path is a string variable.
path = "/root/abc"

Comment: @AvinashBaldi path type is irrelevant, format will convert all the params to string.